long outdoor propane distribution for 300kbtu/hr load
When outdoors and distributing propane (with pipe underground) to 300kbtu outdoor appliance (a water heater) is a pressure regulator typically installed at the tank and also at the appliance?  Or can the full tank pressure be distributed to a regulator at the appliance?
This application is in a very rural location with the tank about 150 ft of buried pipe from the heater.
For the same reason that high-tension power lines are at 100kv+, we would want the propane to be primary liquid or as a high-pressure gas over the long run instead of as a high velocity gas dropping the pressure.
But what is typically done?

What I recall seeing is intermediate-pressure distribution from tank to (outside wall of) house, and a regulator before the gas enters the house. Presumably the folks who write gas codes don't like high pressure gas lines inside the house. Not really up on the details as I've not used gas personally for a while, but that's what I see at a friend's with 1000 gallon buried tank serving a water heater, a dryer and a couple of cooking stoves.

No part of this would be indoors.  The tank is outdoors and the appliance is outdoor water heater and the gas line is mostly buried.  Guess I'm actually asking can I the gas line carry liquid propane to the regulator at the appliance.

you don't really want liquid at the regulator, it'll tend to ice up, and misbehave in interesting ways.

What make and model of gas fired water heater consumes 300 kBTU/h? The US county in which this is being installed may have rules relating to this, also the propane supplier, also insurance company, if any. Ian under the impression that the liquid-to-gas transition is accomplished by a device which is part the tank.

It will be a tankless, most likely, @JimStewart and yes, icing would be a problem with liquid supply, which is why higher-pressure gas is, from what I've seen , the normal mode from tank to house.

I'll contact the supplier to see what pressure to expect at the output of the tankl

Propane is drawn from the large storage tank in vapor form. As noted in comments, heat is absorbed in order to convert liquid to gaseous propane. In other words, the "container" where that occurs gets cold. The tank, having a very large surface area, does a good job of absorbing heat from the surrounding environment to support vaporizing the propane.
Tank pressure can get relatively high (over 100 psi as I recall), so a first-stage regulator is usually present right at the tank. Next comes the line that covers the distance from the tank to the building. In your case, you could put a tee in this line so that a branch of it can go to the location of your new heater.
Near the building (or your new heater) a second-stage regulator brings the intermediate line pressure down to whatever pressure is acceptable at the appliance, which for propane is customarily 11 inches of water column.
The regulators need to be sized for the gas flow they'll carry (cubic feet per hour, or a comparable SI unit). Piping also is sized according to the flow volume.
As a side note: it seems many propane suppliers may be unwilling to provide a tank with a liquid port, so there may be no simple way for you to extract liquid phase from the tank even if you wanted to.

Your side note might be the answer.  The propane must remain in a mixed gas liquid state so long as the pressure is greater or equal to the vapor pressure at the temperature of the propane.  It could be that tank has a built in "regulator" that limits the output pressure (say to 1.5 bar abs) thus as a gas for temperatures > -40C.

@pathfinder Yes, the tank contains a mix of vapor and liquid; liquid withdrawl is done through a port at the bottom of the tank and vapor withdrawl comes from the top, above the liquid level, so that it would be exclusively gas phase. The rest of the system should remain gas phase. It should be unlikely that the plumbing lines' pressure would rise or temperature would fall enough to support re-liquification of the vapor.

The Eastern Gas Company in NH, installs a first stage regulator on the tank with an output pressure of 10psi.  I asked if ever higher pressure is allowed, its not except in specific industrial settings as per regulations.   So In all but the coldest weather it is a gas flowing in the pipe and there is always a regulator installed on the tank.
